Weak Banach vs Arens-Mackey Topology
I've heard that, for general Hilbert $H$, the Arens-Mackey topology is stronger than the weak Banach topology on $B(H).$ Is this true? I find it doubtful.

No, it’s not. If this were true, you would have all weak Banach continuous linear functionals on $B(H)$ are Arens-Mackey continuous. But all bounded linear functionals on $B(H)$ are weak Banach continuous, while only linear functionals induced by trace-class operators are Arens-Mackey continuous, by definition. (According to Wikipedia, the two topologies are supposedly incomparable.)

What is true is that Arens-Mackey topology is stronger than weak operator topology, or weak$^\ast$ topology (aka ultraweak topology). Probably the claim you heard refers to one of those (weak$^\ast$ topology seems especially likely to me) instead of weak Banach topology.

Yes, that is what I figured, but I almost want to think that the weak Banach space is stronger, since it seems like it forces the dual to be far larger than $L^1(H).$ I know this isn't sufficient, but I haven't found a counterexample.

@MilesGould Here is a counterexample: let $H=\ell^2$, $T_n$ be defined by $T_ne_k=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}e_{k+n}$. I claim that $T_n\to 0$ Banach weakly. Indeed, $T_n$ are all compact, so as the dual of compact operators is trace-class operators, it suffices to verify $T_n\to 0$ ultraweakly. But $T_n$ is uniformly bounded, so it suffices to verify $\langle e_l,T_ne_k\rangle\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $k, l$, which is clear. But $T_n\not\to 0$ strongly. Indeed, $|T_ne_1|=1$ for all $n$. So weak Banach topology is not even stronger than the strong operator topology, let alone A-M topology.

Oh wow, using a sequence of compact operators is clever! Did you come up with it yourself?

@MilesGould I did come up with this specific example myself without consulting any reference. (I don’t really know if there are any reference regarding weak Banach topology and A-M topology on $B(H)$. Maybe in Banach space literature? In operator algebras, though, neither of the two topologies is really used.)

Yes, I know they're fairly niche, but I'm trying to study convex/affine closures (w.r.t. each of the operator topologies) of a particular unitary group representation to see if they generate nontrivial unitaries.

@MilesGould If you have a uniformly bounded convex set (which is the case for the convex hall of any subgroup of the unitary group), there is only two possible closures: w.r.t. norm and w.r.t. the weak operator topology. Everything else just reduces to one of those two. There is no reason to consider weak Banach and A-M topologies.

To which case does the weak Banach reduce?

@MilesGould Use Hahn-Banach, and you should be able to figure this out yourself.

(I should say that this is for uniformly bounded convex sets. Without uniform boundedness the WOT and ultraweak closures may no longer be the same, so there would be three closures: w.r.t. norm, w.r.t. ultraweak, and w.r.t. WOT.)
